# Regex Javascript 0-9a-zA-Z plus whitespace, commas etc

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me with this regex? I need something which will ALLOW:

0-9
a-z
A-Z
spaces
hyphens
apostrophes

But disallow all other special characters.

I've got this, but it's not working:

```
"regex":"/^[0-9a-zA-Z/ /-'_]+$/",
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the double quotes around the regex:

```
"regex": /^[0-9a-zA-Z \-'_]+$/,
```

Also make sure you use backslashes to escape special characters, not forward slashes.

Comment: ah sorry, that was the formatting it had to be in for my javascript. That works fine, thanks!

Comment: If you want to allow any white space character, use \s instead of a blank space.

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively remove the outer forward slashes and pass it to the constructor of `RegExp`.

```
"regex" : new RegExp("^[0-9a-zA-Z \-'_]+$")
```

Which is equivalent to the `/pattern/modifiers` syntax (the second argument is an optional string of modifier characters). The `\w` character class matches alphanumeric characters, including underscore, so I think you can shorten your pattern quite a bit by using it.

```
^[\w \-']+$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match underscores as well as alphanumeric charactars (as your code implies), you can use

```
"regex": /^[\w '-]+$/,
```

Also, check out [this online regular expression testing tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Answer (score -4):

```
regExp = /^[0-9A-Za-z\$ ]{0,30}$/;
```